# OperationalError: 250003: Failed to execute request: 'SSLSocket' object has no attribute 'connection' < snowflake.connector trouble

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm running my script in Spyder/conda... was forced to update one thing, which lead to another. Finally, I am stuck trying to fix this error, which is pretty important, because I cannot get my data or fill tables with the result of my analysis without connecting to snowflake.

To verify my connection I am now simply trying to run their boilerplate connection script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import snowflake.connector

# Gets the version
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='email',
    password='pw',
    account='acct'
    )
cs = ctx.cursor()
try:
    cs.execute("SELECT current_version()")
    one_row = cs.fetchone()
    print(one_row[0])
finally:
    cs.close()
ctx.close()
```

I keep getting the "OperationalError: 250003: Failed to execute request: 'SSLSocket' object has no attribute 'connection'" error, and am not sure what to do after reinstalling sqlalchemy, pyarrow, pandas, snowflake-connector-python

Any help/suggestions welcome! I'm out of ideas today.

Comment: What version of Python and snowflake-connector-python are you using? Seems like updating to the latest version of the snowflake connector might solve it? https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/239

Comment: Hi - not sure if it is the cause of your error but you appear not to be setting your Snowflake role in your connection or via a USE ROLE statement

Comment: Have you installed the snowflake python connector first?

pip install --upgrade snowflake-connector-python

Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-install.html#step-1-install-the-connector